# mssql - uncaughtException in Stream Mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams, nodejs-stream, node-mssql

I'm facing the same issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/997):

When trying to use stream and query a table without mentioning the `schema`.

Something like `select * from table` instead of `select * from schema_name.table`. I get the following error:
`mssql uncaughtException RequestError: Invalid object name`

I was able to log the error while listening to `readStream.on('error')` but it still throws an `uncaughtException`.

**Software versions**

```
"mssql": "^7.2.1",
"nodejs":  "12.15.0"
```

**Expected behavior:**

Should be able to catch the uncaughtException

**Actual behavior:**

```
INFO: waaaaaa1
uncaughtException RequestError: Invalid object name 'employee'.
at handleError (.../node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/request.js:388:15)
at Connection.emit (events.js:223:5)
at Connection.emit (.../node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1071:18)
at Parser. (.../node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1176:12)
at Parser.emit (events.js:223:5)
at Readable. (.../node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
```

**Configuration:**

```
    import mssql from 'mssql';
       try {
    mssql.connect({
      server,
      port: Number.parseInt(port),
      database,
      user,
      password,
      options: {
        encrypt: true, // for azure
        trustServerCertificate: trustServerCertificate ? true : false // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
      }
    })
      .then(async client => {
        const readStream = client.request();
        readStream.stream = true;
        const passThroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, './writeMe.json'));
      
        readStream.on('error', () => log.info('waaaaaa1'));
        passThroughStream.on('error', () => log.info('waaaaaa2'));
        writeStream.on('error', () => log.info('waaaaaa3'));

        readStream.pipe(passThroughStream).pipe(writeStream);
        readStream.query(query);
      })
      // the promise error handler
      .catch(() => {
        log.info('waaaaaa4');
      });

    // the main sql error handler:
    mssql.on('error', error => {
      log.error('SQL error1', error);
    });

    // the main sql error handler:
    client.on('error', error => {
      log.error('SQL error2', error);
    });


  }
  catch (err) {
    log.info('catchhhh meee', err);
  }
  finally {
    if(client){
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue using `const readableStream = request.toReadableStream();`

Full code:

```
const request = client.request();
const readableStream = request.toReadableStream();
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, './writeMe.json'));
const passThroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();
readableStream.on('end', () => passThroughStream.end());
readableStream.on('error', (e) => log.info('waaaaaa1'));
readableStream.pipe(passThroughStream).pipe(writeStream);
request.query(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a catch handler to `connect` and more important to the `mssql` object as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#streaming)

```js
mssql.connect({
   // ...
    
 })
.then(() => {
    return readStream.query(query);
})

// the promise error handler
.catch(() => {
    
})

// the main sql error handler:
mssql.on('error', error => {
    console.error('SQL error')
})
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I updated the code, still getting the same error

Comment: What about `readstream.query(query).catch().` ? Another idea would be to catch the error using `process.on('ungaughtException)`, maybe you get additional infos. Also I would try using `await/try catch` within an async function to get the error. I don't have other ideas. good luck

Comment: Is there maybe a `readStream.query(query).on('error')` handler too?

Comment: Yeah, I did it as you can see in code, it prints "waaaaa1"